# Package parameter blank in SSIS catalog

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012, parameter

I have deployed a package with 2 package parameters which had their values set inside the package prior to deployment.  However if I look at those parameters in my SSIS catalog project the values of them are blank.

Is this usual behaviour?  Shouldn't the values have been passed to the parameters in my SSIS catalog?

Thanks

Comment: are the parameters set to sensitive?

Comment: No they are set to required

Answer (score 1):

I would check what is setting the parameter value and make sure it is actually being set by debugging and setting a watch.  Also make sure that your parameter isn't being overwritten by a blank environment variable or something when it's deployed.

Comment: Well I have set a literal value to the parameter in my SSIS package and there are no environments set up.

Answer (score 0):

If parameter is set to required, it means that the paramter value must be entered by user when he runs the deployed package. Set required option to false, and you should be good.